# Regex vba query

Tags: regex, vba, xmlhttprequest

I'm doing a web scraping.
I came across this detail and I don't know how make the regex ( path) .
There are several names in the table,  I want only the data of a person ("yaneth") and their dates are immediately below (Example in red shape).
Any ideas?

[image: http://postimg.org/image/h270fobl9/]

I´m using  vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Regex should work:

```
<td class="ViewDataLeft1"[^>]*?>(.*?)</td>
```

Simply extract the **second** match with `RegExp` object

### Suggestion:

Check the actual source code of the page you are scrapping, as F12 might show different source code than the actual output you are matching against

Feel free to check-out my Scrape HTML Add-In for Excel which scrapes using regular expressions:

http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-scrape-html-add/